# Googleタグマネージャの正規表現について

Tags: 正規表現, google-tag-manager

Googleタグマネージャ（GTM）のトリガーでページタイトルを使用して発火させているのですが、理解できない動きがあったので質問させて下さい。

ページタイトルの構成がPCとスマホで下記のようになっています。

本番
a001
スマホ
a001sp

PCのa001とa002に発火させるため

```
正規表現に一致 a001|a002
```

と指定したところ、a001spとa002spでもタグが発火しました。

特にワイルドカードなど使用していないのですが、どういう原理なのでしょうか。

Comment: ここでの "gtm" とは「Googleタグマネージャ」を指していますか？

Comment: 失礼しました、その通りです。

Comment: https://webtan.impress.co.jp/e/2015/02/20/18976 が参考になると思います。

Comment: 正規表現における完全一致について参考の記事 https://se.miyabikno-jobs.com/re-matching/

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。^a001|^a002であれば理解できるのですが、今回のケースで発火する理由が記事では分かりませんでした。その点をご教示頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: Kouki.Wさんの回答にあるよう、$を付ければよいと思います。正規表現の基本`^` `$` `[ABC]` `[^ABC]` `.` `*`を理解しておくといいですよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちは、はじめまして
ご質問の正規表現では下記のように`部分一致`しているのでヒットします。
https://regex101.com/r/C2w2re/2/

```
a001|a002
```

下記の様に先頭と終端を指定すれば、`完全一致`となります
https://regex101.com/r/C2w2re/1/

```
^a001$|^a002$
```

Comment: 正規表現に一致=部分一致ということなんですね！ありがとうございます、解決しました。